# Qt QML Singleton Intellisense

Tags: c++, qt, singleton, qml, intellisense

Qt QML, they do work, but no intellisense in QML references. Can I achieve intellisense?

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

Item {
    property int iMode: 0
    property bool bSwapLeftRight: false
```

Registering it:

```
qmlRegisterSingletonType(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/GlobalSettings.qml")), "ncs.global", 1, 0, "SingletonSettings" );
```

Second example;:

```
ctxt->setContextProperty("someModel", QVariant::fromValue(ownModel));
ctxt->setContextProperty("globalControl", QVariant::fromValue(globalControl.Get()));
```

First one i achieve IntelliSense in QML whilst using, the second one is the singleton, I do not achieve IntelliSense. Planning to expose some c++ defined enums to QML through this one, but looses value when no IntelliSense is provided..

Question is basically, do Qt Quick and Creator support IntelliSense for singleton classes ? Worthwhile investigating further?

**Adding some more details**, main question is NOT about enum's, but IntelliSense (auto-complete):

```
A few snippets:

main.cpp:
    //Regular Pointer
        SomeModel* ownModel = new SomeModel();
    //Custom Singleton implementation
        GlobalControlSP globalControl = GlobalControl::GetInstance();

    //I did not really want this line. GlobalControl should be singleton, how would this be threated?
        qmlRegisterType<GlobalControl>("ncs.global", 1, 0, "Global");

    //Registering a "Pragma Singleton" file, Intellisense do not work
        qmlRegisterSingletonType(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/GlobalSettings.qml")), "ncs.global", 1, 0, "SingletonSettings" );

        QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
        QQmlContext* ctxt = engine.rootContext();

    //Regular context property, not singleton. Intellisense works
        ctxt->setContextProperty("ownModel", QVariant::fromValue(ownModel));

    //Registering the singleton as context property, Intellisense do not work
        ctxt->setContextProperty("globalControl", QVariant::fromValue(globalControl.Get()));

        engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

globalcontrol.h:
class GlobalControl : public QObject,
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString backcolor READ backcolor NOTIFY backcolorChanged)
    ....

public:
    GlobalControl(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    QString backcolor() const { return m_backColor; }
    ....
    enum EnButton
    {
        DEVICE_START,
        DEVICE_IR,
        .....
    };
    Q_ENUM(EnButton)

public slots:
    void changeMode(int mode);
    void buttonPressed(int button);


some qml file:

//This implementation works:
    NcsButton {
        property int valuent
        id:ir
        text: qsTr("IR")
        width: 66 * widthScaling
        Layout.row: 4
        Layout.column: 1
        fontColor: bIr ? valueColor : textColor
        onClicked: {
            globalControl.buttonPressed(Global.DEVICE_IR)

//This does not work:
    NcsButton {
        id:ir
        text: qsTr("IR")
        width: 66 * widthScaling
        Layout.row: 4
        Layout.column: 1
        fontColor: bIr ? valueColor : textColor
        onClicked: {
            globalControl.buttonPressed(globalControl.DEVICE_IR)
```

Comment: Why don't you expose the C++ Enums using the `Q_ENUM`-Macro?

Comment: I did, it was not working when accessing through the contextproperty. Not from the singleton class. If i made it within another class registered as contextproperty, the enum values was auto-suggested in QML, but did not work. I added a qmlRegisterType<GlobalControl>("ncs.global", 1, 0, "Global"); and it worked

Comment: globalControl.buttonPressed(Global.RADAR_IR) Then i use from same class the enum Global.RADAR_IR to pass to the Singleton function globalControl.buttonPressed. Does not seem clean to me...

Comment: How do you want to expose the enum through the contextProperty? Can you show the code of the object you want to expose? If it works, when you register it as Singleton, why don't you? Why do you want to expose it as contextProperty?

Comment: I added some more code snippets. The main concern is not the enum. The main concern is lacking auto-complete for singletons. It seems after some more googling around that there are reported bugs in this concern, set to resolved with no implementation.... Can i for instance use the singleton as a type?

Comment: The one code that is the most important to understand your problem is the code of `GlobalSettings.qml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution or workaround:

For QML defined singleton, add to Qt compiler QML library a generated file

```
..\..\..\bin\qmlplugindump -relocatable ncs.global 1.0 > plugins.qmltypes
```

For c++ registered singleton, make a "fake" pointer of normal class type. Register. To retrieve the enum from same singleton class, create a UncreatableType:

```
    GlobalControlSP globalControlOrig = GlobalControl::GetInstance();
    GlobalControl* globalControl = globalControlOrig.Get();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("globalControl", QVariant::fromValue(globalControl));
    qmlRegisterUncreatableType<GlobalControl>("ncs.global", 1, 0, "Global", "Singleton");
```

Comment: can you explain more this solution?